# How to replace HTML tags using regexps in R, without using function in replacement?

Tags: python, html, r, regex

I am trying to replace the `<td>` tags by:only `<td>` if they don't have background color info,only `<td backgrouond:'color' >` if background color info is there. In both cases, strip everything else in td tag.

Reproducible example:

```
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=513 style='width:385.0pt;margin-left:-.15pt;border-collapse:collapse'>
<tr style='height:15.0pt'>
<td width=411 nowrap style='width:308.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>hdinka</td>
<td width=103 nowrap valign=bottom style='width:77.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-left:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>kya</td>
</tr>
<tr style='height:15.0pt'>
<td width=411 nowrap style='width:308.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>chika</td>
<td width=103 nowrap valign=bottom style='width:77.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:red;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr style='height:15.0pt'>
<td width=411 nowrap style='width:308.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>pongal</td>
<td width=103 nowrap valign=bottom style='width:77.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>hawk</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So if there is any background in the `<td>` tag the regex result should be something like this: `<td style='background:red;'>` and if there is no background, then result should be just `<td>`

Can this be done without using function in replacement? If not, please tell how.

Comment: so if there is any background in the <td> tag the regex result should be something like this: `<td style='background:red;'>` ?

Comment: @shove exactly. and if there is no background, then result should be just <td>

Comment: Waht? "_something like this:_" where is **this**?

Comment: @MYGz i am really sorry, as it was html tag, it got read in as html by webpage. now i have put it in quotes, so it should be visible

Comment: This was nearly impossible to follow, since most of your `<tags>` were not visible in your question. Please always use the preview window to ensure yur question is understandable before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this BeautifulSoup:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=513 style='width:385.0pt;margin-left:-.15pt;border-collapse:collapse'>
<tr style='height:15.0pt'>
<td width=411 nowrap style='width:308.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>hdinka</td>
<td width=103 nowrap valign=bottom style='width:77.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-left:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>kya</td>
</tr>
<tr style='height:15.0pt'>
<td width=411 nowrap style='width:308.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>chika</td>
<td width=103 nowrap valign=bottom style='width:77.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:red;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr style='height:15.0pt'>
<td width=411 nowrap style='width:308.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>pongal</td>
<td width=103 nowrap valign=bottom style='width:77.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt'>hawk</td>
</tr>
</table>"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.find_all('td'):
    if 'background' in a.attrs['style']:
        b = re.findall(r'background:\w+', a.attrs['style'])
        a.attrs={}
        a.attrs['style'] = b[0]
    else:
        a.attrs={}
print soup
```

Output:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="MsoNormalTable" style="width:385.0pt;margin-left:-.15pt;border-collapse:collapse" width="513">
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td>hdinka</td>
<td>kya</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td>chika</td>
<td style="background:red"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.0pt">
<td>pongal</td>
<td>hawk</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Or with only re module without BeautifulSoup you can do it like so:

```
import re

res = re.sub(r'(<td)(?!.*background).*?(>)', r'\1\2', html)
res = re.sub(r'<td.*(background:\w+).*?>', r'<td style="\1">', res)
print res
```

Output:

```
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=513 style='width:385.0pt;margin-left:-.15pt;border-collapse:collapse'>
<tr style='height:15.0pt'>
<td>hdinka</td>
<td>kya</td>
</tr>
<tr style='height:15.0pt'>
<td>chika</td>
<td style="background:red">&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr style='height:15.0pt'>
<td>pongal</td>
<td>hawk</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you want to do it for all the tags and not just `<td>` you can try like so:

```
res = re.sub(r'(<\w+)(?!.*background).*?(>)', r'\1\2', html)
res = re.sub(r'(<\w+).*(background:\w+).*?>', r'\1 style="\2">', res)
print res
```

Output:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>hdinka</td>
<td>kya</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>chika</td>
<td style="background:red">&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>pongal</td>
<td>hawk</td>
</tr>
</table>
```